# Print current directory using Perl

Tags: perl, directory

I have this code to print the current directory using Perl:

```
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
my $path = abs_path($0);
print "$path\n";
```

But it is displaying the filename of my script along with the directory.

Like this:

> C:\Perl\duration.pl

I want it only to display `C:\Perl\`.

How can I do it?

Comment: are you after the current working directory, or the directory part of the current script's name? those are two different things.

Comment: As per the comment by @Mat, the intent of this question is unclear. Do you want a) the folder of your script b) the current directory the script is working in ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each of the following snippets get the script's directory, which is not the same as the current directory. It's not clear which one you want.

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

say $RealBin;
```

or

```
use Cwd            qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

say dirname(abs_path($0));
```

or

```
use Cwd         qw( abs_path );
use Path::Class qw( file );

say file(abs_path($0))->dir;
```

Comment: Just a note: [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) must be enabled as a feature to be used according to the documentation.

Comment: Since this was the answer that was selected, can the title of the question be changed to ask how to find the *script's* directory?

Comment: @ikegami I did not say that it got the script directory..

Answer (score 47):

To get the current working directory (`pwd` on many systems), you could use `cwd()` instead of `abs_path`:

```
use Cwd qw();
my $path = Cwd::cwd();
print "$path\n";
```

Or `abs_path` without an argument:

```
use Cwd qw();
my $path = Cwd::abs_path();
print "$path\n";
```

See the [Cwd docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) for details.

To get the directory your perl file is in from outside of the directory:

```
use File::Basename qw();
my ($name, $path, $suffix) = File::Basename::fileparse($0);
print "$path\n";
```

See the [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) docs for more details.

Comment: Re "*To get the directory your perl file is in*", That doesn't work if a symlink to the script is used. See my answer for working solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the '$0'

```
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
my $path = abs_path();
print "$path\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
print($ENV{'PWD'});
```

But I think it doesn't work on Windows...

Comment: This works very well, does not require any other code or module. You can write it current working directory but does not answer the original question :)

Comment: This doesn't even work on non-Windows since it relies on the parent setting the variable. And only (some) shells will do that. So much more reliable and portable to use the Cwd module, without making it any more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one simple solution:

```
use Cwd;
my $cwd = cwd();
print "Current working directory: '$cwd()'";
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FindBin`:

```
use FindBin '$RealBin';
print "$RealBin\n";
```

`FindBin` is a standard module that is installed when you install Perl.  To get a list of the standard pragmatics and modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib`.

Answer (score 0):

I used my script in dirs with symlinks.
The script parses the path and executes commands depending on the path.
I was faced with the correct determination of the current path.

Here is example:

```
root@srv apache # pwd
/services/apache

root@srv apache # readlink -f .
/services/apache2225
```

Cwd module disclosures path (analogue of readlink -f)
http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html

```
root@server apache # perl -e 'use Cwd; print cwd . "\n";'
/services/apache2225
```

If you need to get current path like pwd, you can use $ENV{'PWD'}

```
root@srv apache # perl -e 'use Cwd; print $ENV{'PWD'}."\n";'
/services/apache
```

Thank you.