# How to move back one level from the current working directory in perl

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to move back one level from the current working directory but not getting success for doing this .

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw();
my $path = Cwd::cwd();
print "Debug : $path\n";
```

From the above code i can get the current working directory but need to go back one level down.

**Exp : 
Current working directory = 'C:/abc/tmp/folder'
Needed directory = 'C:/abc/tmp'**

Comment: Do you want the current directory, or the directory your script resides in? [Those are very different things.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703705/print-current-directory-using-perl?rq=1#comment6518265_5703705)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any module to change the current working directory. Just

```
chdir '..';
```

will do what you need.

[`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) is a built-in operator, so nothing needs to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Perl chdir() function accepts a ".." argument. If it
does, you can do:

```
chdir("..");
```

to go up a directory.

If not, you will have to do something such as:

```
$currdir = `pwd`; chomp $currdir; # gets current directory
$currdir =~ s/ \/[^\/]+$//; # removes the last / and everything after it
chdir($currdir);
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html). Check the 'fileparse()' or 'dirname()' methods.

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually try to go to the upper directory, i.e. use `..` *somewhere*...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Cwd 'abs_path';

my $path = Cwd::cwd();
print abs_path($path . '/..');
```