# Perl -How do i pass complete directory path name into perl script

Tags: perl

I have a perl script and its been executing from "/root/pkt/sw/se/tool" path and would need the complete   directory path inside the script.

Can you please let me know how would i get the complete path?

## sample.pl

```
 our ($tool_dir);

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 BEGIN {
   $tool_dir = $0;
   my $home_path = $tool_dir
   $home_path =~ s|\w*/\w*/\w*$||;
   my $target_path ="obj/Linux-i686/usr/share/ddlc/lib";
   $lib_dir = "$home_path$target_path";
   unshift(@INC, $lib_dir);
 }
```

And i am executing this script from "pkt/sw/se/tool" path but here i am getting only "pkt/sw/se/tool"  instead of "/root/pkt/sw/se/tool"

my perl script is available  under /root/pkt/sw/se/tools/sample.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the modules already mentioned, never use backticks - unless you fully understand the risks and implications of doing so.  If you do want to run 'pwd' then call it via something like IPC::Run3.

Examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
use IPC::Run3;

# CWD
my $working_dir_cwd = getcwd; 
print "Woring Dir (Cwd): $working_dir_cwd\n";

# IPC::Run3
my ($in, $out, $err);
my @command = qw/pwd/;

run3 \@command, $in, \$out, \$err or die $?;

print "Working Dir (pwd): $out\n";
```

Comment: can you please let me know how do i use 'pwd' via IPC::Run?

Comment: Sorry, I meant IPC::Run3.  Take a look at the example script (edit).  You'll see calling Cwd is a lot less code - but IPC::Run3 is very useful for safely running commands (simple or complex) and capturing the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CWD module (http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html)  (code take  from that page)

```
use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $abs_path = abs_path($file);
```

or you could execute the pwd command

```
$cwd = `pwd`;
```

If you just want the directory,  not the full path,  you could check out an existing answer at [Print current directory using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703705/print-current-directory-using-perl)

Comment: At the line 3 why declare the  `use Cwd 'abs_path';` repeated? declare `abs_path` at the line 1 which is working.

Comment: @Hussain, see the original answer to which I linked and ask there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) to locate directory of original perl script.

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../../../obj/Linux-i686/usr/share/ddlc/lib";
```